# Excel formula evaluating some rows correctly, but others incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

The file is a CSV opened in Excel.

I've formatted all the columns to be general and have checked that calculations are set to automatic and have redone the formulas - double clicked to fill the rows.

Some rows evaluate correctly and others don't.
The ones that don't - I've checked for leading spaces, spaces at end, but can't find any.

The formula I am using is

```
=IF(B2="#NULL!",E2,B2)
```

Any clues as how to fix this?

Comment: how about copying the problematic column > paste in notepad > select all , copy > paste in excel back.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share some genuine data with us to examine, or better share the file link on any suitable platform,, Drop box, Google Drive !!

Comment: *I've checked for leading spaces, spaces at end, but can't find any.* How, exactly, did you do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using builtin ISERR function instead of adding string?

ISERR Function returns True / False if the cell contains #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!

```
=IF(ISERR(B2),E2,B2)
```